# They found the stone-tipped spears created larger 'wounds' than the wooden (ones)

Tags: modifiers, noun-phrases

In this article in the *Daily Mail* https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2735926/Stone-Age-spears-lethal-BULLETS.html is the sentence:

> They found the stone-tipped spears created larger 'wounds' than the wooden **ones**.

Can you omit **ones** here?

Comment: In theory you could leave it out, but as 'stone' and 'wooden' are at opposite ends of the sentence, it is probably easier to understand if you include 'ones' here.

Comment: They found stone-tipped spears created larger 'wounds' than wooden ones. No need for the really.

Comment: @KateBunting Even if you include "ones", you need to remember what "ones" refers to. I don't understand what difference it makes whether to omit "ones" or not, in terms of understanding the sentence.

Comment: @Lambie It's from this Daily Mail article: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2735926/Stone-Age-spears-lethal-BULLETS.html

Comment: In the example in your comment on the deleted answer, _the white model_ and _the black_ are directly contrasted. The Daily Mail sentence would sound awkward to me if it ended "...larger wounds than the wooden."

Comment: @KateBunting Aren't _the stone-tipped spears_ and _the wooden ones_ directly contrasted?

Comment: Yes, of course they are, but with more words in between - that's why I said that including 'ones' _probably_ makes it easier to understand. It's just my opinion, not a rule!!

Answer (score 1):

It is simply not idiomatic. You either use "**ones**" to mean wooden spears or you specify what these other wooden things are.

> They found the stone-tipped spears created larger 'wounds' than the
> wooden "ones"(spears).

or (supposing the other things under consideration are toothpicks)

> They found the stone-tipped spears created larger 'wounds' than the
> wooden "toothpicks".